# SilverStripe behind load balancer

Tags: php, caching, silverstripe, zend-cache, elastic-load-balancer

I've got an instance of SilverStripe running on two servers behind an AWS load balancer. To share the session information I'm running Elasticache Redis server. I'm setting my php session store info as such:

```
ini_set('session.save_handler', 'redis');
ini_set('session.save_path', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:6379');
```

After I've signed into the admin section of the CMS I can jump between servers and it remembers me, however when switching between sections in the CMS the main section doesn't render (an AJAX call). From what I can tell the other server doesn't realise (which ever one you request from second) you already have the CMS admin loaded and in the response headers says to load a new version of JS dependencies which then wigs out the admin and it doesn't load.

Reading into [the docs](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/performance/caching/) SilverStripe is using Zend_Cache for some extra information. I figure if I load the admin interface, then delete the cache directory it would replicate the problem. It doesn't.

I then tried to use [this module](https://github.com/andrelohmann/silverstripe-cache-backends) to change the storage engine that Zend_Cache is using. I added:

```
SS_Cache::add_backend(
    'primary_redis', 
    'Redis',
    array(
        'servers' => array(
            'host' => 'localhost', 
            'port' => 6379, 
            'persistent' => true, 
            'weight' => 1, 
            'timeout' => 5,
            'retry_interval' => 15, 
            'status' => true, 
            'failure_callback' => null
        )
    )
);
SS_Cache::pick_backend('primary_redis', 'any', 10);
```

To my mysite/_config.php and this is storing some cms information in redis like for the key `CMSMain_SiteTreeHints9b258b19199db9f9ed8264009b6c351b`, however this still doesn't fix the problem of changing between servers in the load balanced environment.

Where else could SilverStripe be storing cache data? Have I implemented the module correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default admin interface (assuming you're using 3.x) uses a javascript library called `jquery.ondemand` - this tracks files that have already been included (a rather ancient sort of precursor to the likes of '`require.js`' - only without the AMD, and with CSS support).

To this end the likelihood of this having anything to do with the CMS itself is minimal - considering that the web by nature is stateless, and that the method you're using to save state is shared across your servers (both database and session data).

What is *not* shared across individual instances in your HA cluster is physical files. The cause here is likely (but not definitely going) to be the `mtime` stamp on the end of the URIs supplied to `ondemand` - originally intended to avoid issues with browser caching in respect to theme alterations (developer made or otherwise automated).

The headers as you've no doubt inspected include (*always*, no matter the endpoint chosen by HAProxy, nginx, ELB, or whatever) `X-Include-CSS` and `X-Include-JS` - of which an example looks like:

`X-Include-JS:/framework/thirdparty/jquery/jquery.js?m=1481487203,/framework/javascript/jquery-ondemand/jquery.ondemand.js?m=1481487186,/framework/admin/javascript/lib.js?m=1481487181`[...]

This is on each request, to which `ondemand` can inspect and see what is already included, and what needs to be added.

(Incidentally the size of these headers are what cause `nginx` header buffer issues causing `502` in a 'default' setup.)

### So, what do?

The static files *should* be keeping the same mtime between balanced instances if you are deploying static code - but this is something to check. Generated files on the other hand (such as with `Requirements::combine_files`) will need to be synced on (re)generation between all instances as with all `/assets` for your site, in which case the mtime should persist. `Zend_cache` is quite unlikely to have any affect here, although `APC` may be a factor. Of course the first thing to check in any case is whether or not my premise holds true - e.g. to run the header responses from both back-ends through a diff tool.

Comment: This makes a bit of sense, I'm currently syncing assets on upload. Is there a function I can hook on combined files?

Comment: That was it, running rsync on the system copied the _combinedfiles and the admin started working again.

Comment: I'm not sure how you might achieve it - maybe with a tool like `csync2`, but setting up a file system watch for alterations to initiate a sync (or perhaps just having a scheduled task/cron job run every second or so for it).

Comment: I figured it out and posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

To help those who might come across this and need a solution that hooks into the CMS here is what I did:

```
class SyncRequirements_Backend extends Requirements_Backend implements Flushable {

    protected static $flush = false;

    public static function flush() {
        static::$flush = true;
    }

    public function process_combined_files() {
        // You can write your own or copy from framework/view/Requirements.php
        // Do the required syncing like rsync at the appropriate spot like on successfulWrite
    }
}
```

Add `Requirements::set_backend(new SyncRequirements_Backend());` to your _config.php (mine is a seperate extension but mysite will work too).

The issue with this solution is if the core Requirements_Backend updates you'll be running an older version of code however it is very unlikely to break anything, you've just implemented your own Requirements backend that uses the same code. You could just call the parent instead of doing it all yourself however I couldn't find a way to run the sync only on file write, it would run every time a combined file was requested.